What does this the curly brace mean in an integral
I have seen the following integral given in an answer to one of my questions:
$$
    \int_{z_0}^1 \int_0^1 1\left\{y \le \dfrac{z_0}{x}\right\}dydx
$$
What do the curl braces mean in this context?
Here is a link  to the question I posted and the answer:
The question and answer

This looks like indicator function notation.

In other situations (not here as it has a $\le$), ${x}$ means the fractional part of $x$.

Why do you not ask that to the user who answered your linked question? It is the duty of that person to explain the used notation. A curly brace can mean anything or nothing.

I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked in the post (started by OP) where that notation was used.

More context would be needed to give a confident answer, but one common instance is that “1” is the characteristic function, meaning it equals 1 inside a relevant domain and 0 everywhere else. In this case, the function would equal $1$ so long as $y\le z_0/x$.
